# Reference DOM elements by an iterated ID using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I want to do two things. The first thing is a click event for an unknown quantity of elements to be added to the DOM later as it will constantly be getting updated.

The click even looks like this and is currently working.

```
$("#systemDetails").on("click", "#categoryToggle", function () {
    $(this).closest('table').next().toggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign");
});
```

The id is categoryToggle.

Now I want to reference each individual item with that ID, however you cannot do that when the ID's are all the same. .each() will just return the first element with that ID.

Ideally I want my second piece of code to behave like this:
There is a save function before a section of the DOM is replaced by AJAX, then after it is replaced I want to call this:

```
function recallVis() {
    $("#categoryToggle").each(function (index) {
        if (categoryVis[index]) {
            // hide
            $(this).closest('table').next().hide();
        } else {
            // show
            $(this).closest('table').next().show();
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to iterate through either all ID's of the same name, OR iterate through a list of ID's in say, this format: ID1, ID2, ID3... etc... And maintain a single click event handler that works for all items in the format ID(number)?

Or am I stuck using classes in my selector if I want to use JQuery's .each() method?

Comment: See [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).  You can use a "starts with" selector to find all `id`'s starting with some common set of characters.  However, every `id` ***must*** be unique on the page.

Comment: IDs **can't** be the same; that's why it's called an "ID." Using the same ID on more than one element results in an invalid document. If you want to identify a group (or "class") of elements, use a class name, not an ID. What you have may work, but then not work the next time jQuery or the browser's next dot release comes out.

Comment: "*Or am I stuck using classes*" - why do you consider using class-names as being 'stuck', or inferior in some way?

Comment: Sparky, seems you might have an answer. You should post it as one. If I use starts with, will it allow me to access the particular index of an item it returns? How would I incorporate it to create a click event that startswith("someID")?

Comment: TJ incorporated my suggestion into his answer, so I'm ok with that.  Yes, you can get the index within the `.each()`.  Again, see the docs:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: @JWBaker: You'd just use the same selector with `on`, I've updated my answer to show it (for both class -- because classes really are the standard way to do this and less faff than IDs with numeric suffixes -- and for starts-with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a class name rather than ID, since IDs have to be unique and managing IDs with suffixes (`ID1`, `ID2`, etc. as you mentioned in the question) is a pain. But it can be done.

Using a class:

```
function recallVis() {
    // v--- Change is here
    $(".categoryToggle").each(function(index) {
        if (categoryVis[index]) {
            // hide
            $(this).closest('table').next().hide();
        } else {
            // show
            $(this).closest('table').next().show();
        }
    });
}
```

...and your delegated `click` handler would be:

```
// Change is here ---------------v
$("#systemDetails").on("click", ".categoryToggle", function () {
    // ...
});
```

Using `ID1`, `ID2`, etc.:

```
function recallVis() {
    $("[id^=categoryToggle]").each(function(index) {
        if (categoryVis[index]) {
            // hide
            $(this).closest('table').next().hide();
        } else {
            // show
            $(this).closest('table').next().show();
        }
    });
}
```

...and your delegated `click` handler would be:

```
// Change is here ---------------vvvvv--------------v
$("#systemDetails").on("click", "[id^=categoryToggle]", function () {
    // ...
});
```

That uses the "attribute starts with" selector `^=` to look for any element with an `id` attribute that starts with `categoryToggle`.

Comment: Curious if you know of a performance difference using class over a "starts with" selector.

Comment: @Sparky: Was just adding a "starts-with" option, amusingly. I doubt there's any performance difference that would matter in the real world (what difference there is I bet comes out on the side of the class selector, but that's just gut instinct I would test it before I trusted it if I really needed to know). But managing the indexes on the IDs is usually a pain, and there's really no reason to do it.

Comment: Actually, I only asked the question when your answer only contained the class selector.  So I tend to agree it would make no difference in the real world.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. You are right, I feel there is no real reason I would need to manage ID suffix's.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ID values are truly unique! Once that's done, take a look at two multiple elements selection approaches that could work for your project:

1) Using a single class value + class-based selection :

```
$(".myselectorclass").each(function (index) { ...do something... });
```

2) Using unique IDs for each iterable element -- Try using an attribute based selector rather than `#ID`

```
$("DIV[id^='myIdPrefix']").each(function (index) { ...do something... });
```

Approach #2 addresses your thought on selecting "ID1, ID2, etc".  Hope this helps!

JQuery Selector Info:
General - http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
'Starts With' - http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/